# How to Add Product Variation with Multiple Images via WooCommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So I've seen in the api that u can send via CURL or PHP library 1 image in variations. But you cannot add more than 1.

Like we have Black, Blue and they both have 4 images. But when u select the color will only show up the first image.
An example found on github -> https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1264099/24268988/5f51a7de-0fee-11e7-87e2-218a9778dc01.png

```
'variations' => [
    'image' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_front.jpg',
            'position' => 0
        ]
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'option' => 'Black',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Size',
            'option' => 'S',
        ]
    ],
]
```